# Purely Functional Racket

Tags: functional-programming, racket, purely-functional

What are all Racket procedures that mutate state?
I'm trying to create a program with as little side-effects as possible

So, I'd do something like:

```
#lang racket/base
(provide (except-out (all-from-out racket/base) set! …more here…))
```

What else should I exclude besides set! ?
Is there a complete list somewhere of all impure functions?

Oh, and the program also uses #lang racket/gui (which is mostly impure, by what I could gather). So that may be tricky...

Thank you.

Comment: Can you say more about why -- i.e. what you're trying to do? Because "immutable" is relative to some context. No program is "immutable" relative to CPU and RAM state. Less extremely, a function might _behave_ purely, but its implementation might use memoization -- does that count, for your purpose? I'm not sure what context you care about. In any case, GUIs are typically handled with stateful OOP, as in Racket.

Comment: I want to avoid using side effects so my functions will behave purely because I believe it'll be easier to test and reason about my program.


If 'racket/gui' requires a stateful design then what can I do to mitigate the need?

Answer (score 7):

There is no pre-built list of non-pure functions in Racket.
If you just refrain from using anything which has a ! in the name, you will get close.

Note that you can use mutable data structures and still be programming in a purely functional way - as long as you don't mutate them.